# keep Facebook authentication when accessing webpage thru UIWebView after login with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully integrated the facebook ios SDK in my app so that user can post to their wall through a feed dialog.

However, I would like to post an open graph object through my app but since this is currently only supported on webpages (is this correct?), I suppose I can load the webpage with the meta tags inside a UIWebView. If I do so, however, I believe user have to authenticate my web app as well?

Is there a way to not need the user to authenticate my web app inside the UIWebView when they have already login through the iOS SDK? I would like to keep the iOS SDK login process because it doesn't require user to enter their facebook details (assuming they have the facebook app installed of coz)

thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like i am able to post feeds in UIWebView after logging in with the iOS SDK. I did logout of facebook on my safari app just in case....